# MySQL: How to set maximum row property in table?

Tags: mysql

I want to set that my table will only have 4 rows or 4 records. For this I've created a table using the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `zero`.`table_limit` 
   `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=4
```

I think it is right still when I trying to insert more than 4 rows, it is not showing any error.

Can any body tell me where i m doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: ok i will use trigger , we can use it and check select * from table name , how we can use this value, to further processing, i think trigger never return ....

Answer (score 1):

Quoting http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html:

The maximum number of rows you plan to store in the table. This is not a hard limit, but rather a hint to the storage engine that the table must be able to store at least this many rows.